# How to "send" a method to inside another method?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
public class Mail {
  public String Obfuscate(String email) {
    return email.Replace("@", "at").Replace(".", "dot");
  }
}
```

I am calling the method Obfuscate in a class, as follows:

```
public class Resolver {
  public Data GetData () {
    return new Data { Email = new Mail().Obfuscate(myEmail) };
  }
  public String Translate(string value) { /* Some Code */ }
}
```

The problem is that Obfuscate does the replacement in English: @ > at, . > dot

But in the Resolver class the method Translate does exactly what I need ...

How can I "pass" the Translate method to the Obfuscate method so this one uses it to translate @ and . to at and dot in the current language?

So the code line inside Obfuscate:

```
return email.Replace("@", "at").Replace(".", "dot");
```

Would be become:

```
return email.Replace("@", Translate("@")).Replace(".", Translate("."));
```

Where Translate would be the method that I am "passing" to it.

Than You,
Miguel

Comment: I would recommend something like what Vernacular does: a static class with a Translate method. If you can't change this, pass a delegate as a parameter to Obfuscate : public String Obfuscate(String email, Func<String, String> translator)

Comment: This is exactly what delegates are for. You may use Func. But I believe, there should be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @BartoszKP's answer is the right design decision.  For completeness, here's how to do what you asked.

Change Mail to take a `Func<string,string>`:

```
public class Mail {
  public String Obfuscate(String email, Func<string,string> translate) {
    return email.Replace("@", translate("at")).Replace(".", translate("dot"));
  }
}
```

And pass your `Translate` method to it:

```
public class Resolver {
  public Data GetData () {
    return new Data { Email = new Mail().Obfuscate(myEmail, Translate) };
  }
  public String Translate(string value) { /* Some Code */ }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider a different design:

```
public interface ITranslator
{
    string Translate(string s);
}

public class Obfuscator
{
    public Obfuscator(ITranslator translator)
    {
        this.translator = translator;
    }

    public string Obfuscate(string email)
    {
       var at = translator.Translate("at");
       var dot = translator.Translate("dot");

       return email.Replace("@", at).Replace(".", dot);
    }

    private ITranslator translator;
}

public class EnglishTranslator : ITranslator
{
    public string Translate(string s)
    {
        return s;
    }
}

public class PolishTranslator : ITranslator
{
    public PolishTranslator() //or `FileInfo dictionaryFile` parameter perhaps
    {
        // for simplicity
        translations = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        translations.Add("at", "malpa");
        translations.Add("dot", "kropka");
    }

    public string Translate(string s)
    {
        return translations[s];
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> translations;
}
```

However you really should consider using a [`ResourceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx). Resource related mechanisms are designed to deal with translations.